# IBM Connections 5 POST giving 403 for forum, blog, board posts from Android App

Tags: cordova, atom-feed, ibm-connections

I am working on mobile app (using cordova for android application ) for IBM Connections. I had already created Forum reply for IBM Connection 3.0.1 which was working fine. Now when server got upgraded to IC 5 it has started giving 403 error.

I am creating POST as per IBM Documentation here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+5.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_a_standalone_forum_reply_programmatically_ic50&content=apicontent

I don't see any changes in documentation for 3.0.1 and 5

**EDIT :**

Here is request

URL: https: //test.server.com/forums/atom/replies?topicUuid=915e3cb9-7a54-4259-a904-890abd6cc327

```xml
<entry xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title type="text"><![CDATA[Re: Again TEsting]]></title>
<content type="text"><![CDATA[test reply]]></content>
<category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="forum-reply"></category>
<thr:in-reply-to xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0" ref="urn:lsid:ibm.com:forum:915e3cb9-7a54-4259-a904-890abd6cc327" href="https: //test.server.com/forums/atom/topic?topicUuid=915e3cb9-7a54-4259-a904-890abd6cc327" />
</entry>
```

and I am getting this response

```xml
<error xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
<code>403</code>
<message>You are not authorized to perform the requested action.</message>
<trace></trace>
</error>
```

**EDIT 2**

Just Found out that same error I am getting for All `POST` requests
New Forum Topic, Blog Reply, Create Blog, Reply on Board.

Same things work from iPhone (native) application

Comment: can you post the body of the response ?

Comment: @PaulBastide I have added request and response

Comment: if you do a GET operation on that URL does it return data?

Comment: @PaulBastide Yes, before sending reply I am listing all previous replies which are rendered correctly

Comment: is there anything on the SystemOut.log file for the JVM supporting Forums?

Comment: @PaulBastide No, there is nothing in SystemOut.log file

Comment: yes on AppServer, I tried to debug with Server guy to get some clue

Comment: what you have above should work, I recommend you open a Support Request for IBM.

Comment: Running into a similar issue. Has this been resolved?

Comment: I found the root cause, IBM connections blocks requests as cordova app sends Origin header  as 'file://' which was not case for native. had to write custom native plugin :(

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was testing with Chrome and Postman. Might have the same cause. Issue is also described here (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO79992) and supposedly fixed in 4.5. Apparently it resurfaced in v5.

Comment: Workaround on making this work with Chrome/ Postman can be found here:  http://linqed.eu/2016/07/05/getting-the-ibm-connections-api-to-play-nice-with-postman-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

Try using a VPN service that would definitely help you out, You can try gom vpn chrome extension. that 's pretty nice and can help you solve you problem very easily. Get it from here: http://www.hackbs.com/gom-vpn-free-tricks-to-bypass-cyberoam-2015/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to access the same page from some other pc or laptop? If the problem persists then it may be beacuse the webiste owner has restricted you from access that page. Well there's a simple soln. to it..Install gom vpn extension from [here](http://www.hackbs.com/gom-vpn-free-tricks-to-bypass-cyberoam-2015/).it will let you bypass this restriction in seconds.